# Give input with CliWrap

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I have a c# Application, which should control a CLI application. The CLI does some work and outputs a specific string and then waits for a response from the user. I wanted to automate that process, but can't figure out how to write with CliWrap. The CliWrap closes with an error as soon as I try to write with streamWriter.

```
using (Stream stream = new Stream()) 
  {
      using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)) 
      {
          var cmd = Cli.Wrap("longRunningProcess")
            .WithStandardInputPipe(PipeSource.FromStream(stream));

          await foreach (var cmdEvent in cmd.ListenAsync())
          {
              switch (cmdEvent)
              {
                  case StartedCommandEvent started:
                      Debug.WriteLine($"Process started; ID: {started.ProcessId}");
                      break;
                  case StandardOutputCommandEvent stdOut:
                      if (stdOut.Text.Contains("expectedOutput")) 
                      {
                          // write this input: 1 followed by enter and resume to reading the input
                          streamWriter.Write("1");
                          streamWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                          streamWriter.Flush();
                      }
                      Debug.WriteLine($"Out> {stdOut.Text}");
                      break;
                  case StandardErrorCommandEvent stdErr:
                      Debug.WriteLine($"Err> {stdErr.Text}");
                      break;
                  case ExitedCommandEvent exited:
                      Debug.WriteLine($"Process exited; Code: {exited.ExitCode}");
                      break;
              }
          }
      }
  }:
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong when writing to the CLI?

- Tried changing the streams
- Tried other input forms like fromString or FromFile
- Looked up solutions everywhere